# Adding subview within UIControl in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController which is tied to a xib and I would want to instantiate it and add the view inside a UIControl but is not working.

Inside the UIControl class I am doing the following:

```
func ShowSecondaryView() {
    let secondaryViewController = SecondaryViewController()
    self.addSubView(secondaryViewController.view)
}
```

However, I am not seeing anything added to the screen and I am not able to click on anything as if there is an invisible view added to the front.  I know I am missing something obvious but could someone point me to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SecondaryViewController is designed by xib, right? You should instantiate it from xib like this:

```
func ShowSecondaryView() {
    let secondaryViewController = SecondaryViewController(nibName: "SecondaryViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.addSubView(secondaryViewController.view)
}
```